# Reconstruction formula for a function of moderate decrease

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to show that, for a function $f$ of moderate decrease and $\hat{f}(\xi)$ supported in $I=[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$,

> > $$f(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} f(n)K(x-n)$$

where $K(y) = \frac{sin( \pi y)}{\pi y}$

The book provides the hint to show that $\hat{f(\xi)} = \chi_I(\xi) \sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} f(n)e^{-2 \pi i n \xi}$  where $\chi$ is the characteristic function

I know that $${K}(\xi) = \hat{\chi}_I(\xi) $$ and I can see Poisson's summation formula inside there somewhere, but I can't proceed because I can't come up with justification.

If I multiply the inside of the first sum by $1 = e^{-2 \pi i n \xi}e^{-2 \pi i(x-n) \xi}$ I have $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} f(n)K(x-n)e^{-2 \pi i n \xi}e^{-2 \pi i(x-n) \xi}$$ and I thought about applying Poisson to get this to be equal to:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} \hat{f} \ast \chi_I (\xi)$$but this doesn't seem right. However, I have the suspicion that convolutions are involved somewhere otherwise I don't know how to justify taking the FT/inverse FT of a product of functions.  I've been stuck for a while, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a sketch of proof in the Wikipedia article about [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).